# Sumifs inside an If statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel worksheet that needs a formula to check 2 dropdowns and sum based on the selections.

1st Dropdown: Select Team

2nd Dropdown: select timezone

My current formula does not use the timezone dropdown at the moment because when my formula is true or false it prints the sumifs formula instead of working it out.

E4 is a timezone dropdown with PST, CAT ect..

B2 is a team dropdown with TeamA, TeamB etc...

Formula: `=SUMIFS(Items!C:C;Items!F:F;[@Date];Team;$B$2)`

New Formula needed:

`=IF(E4="PST";"=SUMIFS(Items!C:C;Items!F:F;[@Date];Team;$B$2)";"=SUMIFS(Items!C:C;Items!I:I;[@Date];Team;$B$2)")`

If **true** it displays: `=SUMIFS(Items!C:C;Items!F:F;[@Date];Team;$B$2)` but it should rater work out the formula and display `6`

I have tried working the other way e.g:

`=SUMIFS(IF(.....))` also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes.

`=IF(E4="PST";SUMIFS(Items!C:C;Items!F:F;[@Date];Team;$B$2);SUMIFS(Items!C:C;Items!I:I;[@Date];Team;$B$2))`

That is causing it to display as string.